# How to remove from the data the rows of with fixed number of elements?

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

Consider the data which has the form

```
data = {{x1,y1,z1},{x2,y2,z2,t2},{x3,y4,z4,t4},{x5,y5,z5},...}
```

How to remove the rows containing three elements from the data?

I.e., to obtain

```
dataprime = {{x2,y2,z2,t2},{x3,y4,z4,t4},...}
```

Comment: Maybe you ask for `DeleteCases[data, _?(Length[#] == 3 &)]`...

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher : sorry, already corrected this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Any one of these would do:

```
Cases[data, Except[_?(Length[#] == 3 &)]]
DeleteCases[data, _?(Length[#] == 3 &)]

Select[data, Length[#] != 3 &]

Delete[data, Position[data, _?(Length[#] == 3 &)]]

data /. {_, _, _} -> Nothing
data /. {Repeated[_, {3}]} -> Nothing
```

They all return: `{{x2, y2, z2, t2}, {x3, y4, z4, t4}}`

Answer (score 5):

Also

```
Pick[data, Unitize[-3 + Length /@ data], 1]
```